# How to manually add a reference to a DLL in VS2015 MVC 6 project?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am upgrading a project which from MVC 5, to MVC 6.

The project has a 3rd party dll (which is available on Nuget), and it has dependency on WebActivator.dll.

WebActivator is no longer available on nuget. (There is a new version which replaced it.)

This is problematic however, because the 3rd party dll has a reference to WebActivator, but I don't see how to get it into the project.

I have a copy of the DLL, but with VS 2015, I don't see a way to "browse" and then add an existing dll which could be done in VS 2013.

How do I manually add this reference in a VS 2015 project?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this which was to go into the nuspec file and change the dependency from WebActivator to WebActivatorEx.

The nuspec file was located at:

```
c:\Users\myUserName\.dnx\packages\ThePackageName\1.5.4\*.nuspec
```